# Nginx configuration AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, nginx

I have a AngularJS project that was running on Node Server now I am using NGINX web server and shifted my project from Node to NGINX.
nginx configuration is

```
location /bourbonweb {
root /var/sites/bourbon/;
index index.html;
location ~ ^/bourbon/bourbonweb/(.+\.html)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    root /var/sites/bourbon/;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index index.html;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/sites/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
location ~* /bourbonweb/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
     root /var/sites/bourbon/;
}
```

It's working.
and project directory structure
1.    bourbon
2.    Inside bourbon folder bourbonweb, bower_components, node_modules etc
3.    enter code hereinside bourbonweb my css,js, img, views, controllers, directives, services are there.

The problem I am facing 404 not found error. It's only not loading from bower_components folder. rest all file is getting load. Only AngularJS modules not geting load from bower_components.

Please help me out 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to show more code, in particular, your node's routing logic.